# How to Add two Texbox value in one column of datagridview in vb

Tags: vb.net

For example : Textbox 1
Textbox 2

Datagridview columns 1
Textbox1 value
textbox value2

Comment: Are you asking how to concatenate string values? or are you asking to merge column headers? so multiple columns share the same heading.  A clear and concise explanation of the problem, what you've tried to date and intended out comes in your question will make it a lot more answerable.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit generic but I think I know what you mean. So as far as I'm concerned you want to merge two fields from a list of data into one field in the gridview, right?
If that's the case here's the answer

```
Private Sub myGridView_CustomUnboundColumnData(sender As Object, e As CustomColumnDataEventArgs) Handles myGridView.CustomUnboundColumnData
    If e.Column.FieldName = "textBox1" Then
          e.Value = myData.textBox1 " - " myData.textBox2
    End If
End Sub
```

This works for me but i have a DevExpress license. I'm pretty sure it won't matter.